# select columns with contains only numeric values >= 0

Tags: r

I want to select columns with numeric values >= 0.

```
cities <- c("Nantes", "Paris", "London", "Munchen")
variable1 <- c(-100, 20, 5, 30)
variable2 <- c(10, 13, 2, 30)
variable3 <- c(10, 200, -5, 300)
df <- data.frame(cities, variable1, variable2, variable3)
```

What I tried without success :

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% select_if(is.numeric >=0)
```

What I want :

```
cities variable2
1  Nantes        10
2   Paris        13
3  London         2
4 Munchen        30
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df %>%
 select_if(~ is.numeric(.) && all(. >= 0))

  variable2
1        10
2        13
3         2
4        30
```

If the goal is to keep columns with strings or with all values >= 0, then:

```
df %>%
 select_if(~ is.character(.) || all(. >= 0))

   cities variable2
1  Nantes        10
2   Paris        13
3  London         2
4 Munchen        30
```

Comment: can I keep character values too ?

Answer (score 2):

in base R

```
df[c(T,apply(df[-1],2,function(x) all(x>=0)))]

   cities variable2
1  Nantes        10
2   Paris        13
3  London         2
4 Munchen        30
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Filter` in `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) is.numeric(x) && all(x > 0), df)
#  variable2
#1        10
#2        13
#3         2
#4        30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `paste0` all columns into strings and substract (`-`) those columns `which` match the pattern `-`:

```
df[, -which(grepl("-", apply(df, 2, paste0, collapse = " ")))]
   cities variable2
1  Nantes        10
2   Paris        13
3  London         2
4 Munchen        30
```